# Which is a better practice in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm learning mobile dev using flutter, with little programming background. Just want to know which is a better practice and does it affect performance of the code. Let say I have 5 RaisedButton 
Should I do like this. Or make a different file and access the constructor of the new class? The only difference is the text on the button and the route

```
children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                elevation: 0.1,
                child: Text('Attandence Tag'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserTag()),
                  );
                },
              ),

              RaisedButton(
                elevation: 0.1,
                child: Text('Add New Student'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateUser()),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

thanks for answering

Comment: Please change the question title, It will be great if you add what you required directly.

Comment: @jitsm555 please explain why is it I need to change my question title? I simply asked **"Which is a better practice"**, whether **directly used Widgets multiple time** OR **make another file (model) and call it** to simplify the code.
Also, you didn't explain why do I need to use **switch case** in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have special styling it's definitely worth to define it in an other file.
If you want to change the style you just have one widget to change it's easier and it simplify your code.

But (because nothing is perfect), Flutter produce easily spaghetti code, so it's up to you to make it clear the way you want. The best way is the one you feel comfortable with, and you have to try things to discover it.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply :)
I did try to make another file and use the constructor, but just like you said, still produce those spaghetti code. For now I dont found any effect on my app performance

Comment: @AJTech: Have you added the switch case for it.

Comment: @jitsm555 would you mind to explain the use of switch case in this situation?